# Having been invited or being invited

Tags: word-choice

Can't I use both forms "being" and "having been" with the past participle when talking about actions in the past?

1."I appreciated being invited." (Past)
Or "I appreciate (now) being invited (earlier) ." =A different meaning.

2. "I appreciate being invited to her party last night."
3. "I appreciate having been invited (with or without "last night").
4. "I appreciated having been invited to her party (with or without "last night).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the options you give are correct. "Being" is a gerund and therefore untensed. The perfect form ("having been") emphasizes that the event happened at an earlier time. Either can describe a past action.

However, note that this works because we often "appreciate" events that are in the past. It does not work so well with all verbs. E.g.:

> I like being invited to her party last night. (This is fairly unusual.)

> I like having been invited to her party last night. (This is better grammatically.)

Comment: Is there any reason one cannot use 'having been' for something that is currently taking place, or yet to do so? Eg. *I appreciate having been invited here this evening (but the whole thing seems pointless)* or *I appreciate having been invited to attend the graduation ceremony next Saturday (but I am wondering why they have done so)*. They sound idiomatic to me. The past sense implied in the use of the perfect relates to the time of the invitation, not to the event itself - doesn't it?

Comment: @WS2 Yes, in both of your sentences, "having been invited" means that the invitation occurred at an earlier time. The invitation was not "currently taking place, or yet to do so"; it was in the past.

Comment: But there are two quite separate moments in time here - the time of the invitation and the time of the event. If the first of those is in the past, though the second is yet to happen, I see no problem with using "having been invited".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, would it be wrong with "remember" too as it is wrong with"like"? For example, I remember being invited to her party and I remember having been invited to her party.

Comment: @WS2 Oh, I see what you mean. "Having been" refers only to the invitation, so it's fine grammatically because it was in the past. However, some people might assume that the party was also in the past. To be clear, you could say something like, "I appreciate having been invited to the party that she is throwing tomorrow."

Comment: @AntoniaA It is fine with "remember" because we normally remember past events. Both sentences you wrote are OK.